# I want a data from text file and save into the database

Tags: java, struct

**Data is like**

```
{10|3|IN0356|IN0356RG|2|22-06-2016|V1.1|||||
20|1|04||02|02|02|02|02|02|02|02|02|02|01|||01|10088499405447|MR|Anantha|sadvichar|Lochanvala||Mr|Anand|Sharma|Upadhyay|Mr Anand  Sharma Upadhyay|1|MR|Rajeev|vxvxase|Shah|MR Rajeev vxvxase Shah|vvxvx|Nanditha|vxxvasew|Pandit|vvxvx Nanditha vxxvasew Pandit|M|01|IN|S-02|02-12-1962|||||||||01|02|AF||AF||1|Li|lin|line|city|Hassan||IN|573201|||2|0|gdfgd|ssfsdf|sdfsdf|dsfsdfsdfsdf|Hassan||IN|573201||3|0|Li|lin|line|city||IN|573201||||||||||||01-06-2016|dfgdfgdfg|01-06-2016|01|dgfdgdfg|gdfgdfg|dfgdgdgdf|dgdgdg|FI Registration472|IN0356|1|2|||3|||||||
30|1|F|qwert||01|02|||||
40|1|1|||mkm|Dileep|kmk|mkmk|||||||||||||||||||||||||MKNPO2356K||||||||||||||||||||||01-06-2016|kmk|01-06-2016|01|mk|km|km|mkm|DOTEX|IN106||||||
40|1|1|||mkm|Dileep|kmk|mkmk|||||||||||||||||||||||||MKNPO2356K||||||||||||||||||||||01-06-2016|kmk|01-06-2016|01|mk|km|km|mkm|DOTEX|IN106||||||
70|1|10088499405447_02_02062016170054.jpg|02|||||||
70|1|10088499405447_09_02062016170054.tiff|09|||||||
70|1|10088499405447_08_02062016170054.tif|08|||||||
20|2|04||02|02|02|02|02|02|02|02|02|02|1|||01|10095197636617|hg|fhgfhg||ytrytr||Mr|Anand|Sharma|Upadhyay|Mr Anand  Sharma Upadhyay|1|MR|Rajeev||Shah|MR Rajeev  Shah|hjgjh|Nanditha||Pandit|hjgjh Nanditha  Pandit|M|01|IN|S-02|02-12-1962|||||||||02|01|AU|1235|IN|Patna|1|Ranga Mandira|||Ratnagiri|361||AF||||N|0|NSE|Mahamandal||Ratnagirishhhhhhh|Mumbai|MH|IN|400051||3|0|Madhava nagara|manehala||Ratnagiri||AF|||||||||||||02-05-2016|gjhgjhghj|03-05-2016|01|gjhgg|tyrytryt|uytfyutfytu|ytuytuyt|FI Registration472|IN0356|3||||6|||||||
30|1|F|123456||01|02|||||
30|1|E|123456789012|||02||||||
70|2|10095197636617_02_31052016161747.jpg|02|||||||
70|2|10095197636617_09_31052016161747.tiff|09|||||||
70|2|10095197636617_08_31052016161747.tiff|08|||||||}
```

I want a data according to section wise
mean:
as per the record there are two records
this section record having 20, 30 ,40,70 fields each
i want fetch this records from text  file and save to the database
according to each customers 
first customer records like

```
{20|1|04||02|02|02|02|02|02|02|02|02|02|01|||01|10088499405447|MR|Anantha|sadvichar|Lochanvala||Mr|Anand|Sharma|Upadhyay|Mr Anand Sharma Upadhyay|1|MR|Rajeev|vxvxase|Shah|MR Rajeev vxvxase Shah|vvxvx|Nanditha|vxxvasew|Pandit|vvxvx Nanditha vxxvasew Pandit|M|01|IN|S-02|02-12-1962|||||||||01|02|AF||AF||1|Li|lin|line|city|Hassan||IN|573201|||2|0|gdfgd|ssfsdf|sdfsdf|dsfsdfsdfsdf|Hassan||IN|573201||3|0|Li|lin|line|city||IN|573201||||||||||||01-06-2016|dfgdfgdfg|01-06-2016|01|dgfdgdfg|gdfgdfg|dfgdgdgdf|dgdgdg|FI Registration472|IN0356|1|2|||3||||||| 30|1|F|qwert||01|02||||| 40|1|1|||mkm|Dileep|kmk|mkmk|||||||||||||||||||||||||MKNPO2356K||||||||||||||||||||||01-06-2016|kmk|01-06-2016|01|mk|km|km|mkm|DOTEX|IN106|||||| 40|1|1|||mkm|Dileep|kmk|mkmk|||||||||||||||||||||||||MKNPO2356K||||||||||||||||||||||01-06-2016|kmk|01-06-2016|01|mk|km|km|mkm|DOTEX|IN106|||||| 70|1|10088499405447_02_02062016170054.jpg|02||||||| 70|1|10088499405447_09_02062016170054.tiff|09||||||| 70|1|10088499405447_08_02062016170054.tif|08||||||| }
```

second customer record like

`{20|2|04||02|02|02|02|02|02|02|02|02|02|1|||01|10095197636617|hg|fhgfhg||ytrytr||Mr|Anand|Sharma|Upadhyay|Mr Anand Sharma Upadhyay|1|MR|Rajeev||Shah|MR Rajeev Shah|hjgjh|Nanditha||Pandit|hjgjh Nanditha Pandit|M|01|IN|S-02|02-12-1962|||||||||02|01|AU|1235|IN|Patna|1|Ranga Mandira|||Ratnagiri|361||AF||||N|0|NSE|Mahamandal||Ratnagirishhhhhhh|Mumbai|MH|IN|400051||3|0|Madhava nagara|manehala||Ratnagiri||AF|||||||||||||02-05-2016|gjhgjhghj|03-05-2016|01|gjhgg|tyrytryt|uytfyutfytu|ytuytuyt|FI Registration472|IN0356|3||||6||||||| 30|1|F|123456||01|02||||| 30|1|E|123456789012|||02|||||| 70|2|10095197636617_02_31052016161747.jpg|02||||||| 70|2|10095197636617_09_31052016161747.tiff|09||||||| 70|2|10095197636617_08_31052016161747.tiff|08|||||||}`

but text file comes with many records  and i want to split this section customer wise

Comment: The question is completely unclear...

Comment: Please look at the question preview before submitting. Try to [edit] your question

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**Step 1:** Read your file line by line.

**Step 2:** Clean your data.

**Step 3:** Store data to database.

```
 // Open the file
 FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
 InputStreamReader(fstream));

 String strLine;

//Read File Line By Line
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
  // Now split line by pipe symbol and convert to array
  String[] value_split = strLine.split("|");
  //Clear your data further if nessasry 
  //Store data to DB here
}

//Close the input stream
br.close();
```